# Java - extend an interface

Tags: java, interface, extend

Is it correct to extend an empty interface? I just need to have a method (EventPlayer) with a parameter (EventCLass myEvent) that could be one time a class and the next time another class.

```
public interface EventClass {
  // ... empty ...
}

public interface EventClassExt1 extends EventClass {

    public void firstEvent();

    public void secondEvent();
}


public interface EventClassExt2 extends EventClass {

    public void thirdEvent(String text);
}

public EventPlayer(final EventCLass myEvent)
```

Comment: Interface with out a method is correct but your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is correct. it is called **Marker Interface**.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's OK to do that.

When an interface has no methods, it's generally called a [*marker interface*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern); [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) is one of many examples of such an interface from the JDK.

Also, you probably don't want "class" in your interface name. Just `Event` is a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

*Is it correct to extend a Class that has not other object in it?*

I assume by this you mean an empty interface.

This is something that was used in Java a lot before they had annotations to sign a class is of that type ( from Java 5 ).

What you are doing is correct - basically you are marking the extended interfaces/classes type of `EventClass` but I would use annotation which is the new way to do that

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html